# How to use ajax to update label from count from mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I know ajax is probably the best method to do this.

So, i have this php file which returns a count:

```
<?php
    include('globals.php');
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM solicitacoes WHERE visualizada = 0");
    $resultado = mysqli_fetch_array ($query);
    $sem_visualizar = $resultado['total'];
    return $sem_visualizar;
```

And i have this on my main page:

```
<?php
    if($_SESSION['funcao_corrente']=="adm" || $_SESSION['funcao_corrente']=="analista"){
    echo '<label onclick="mudaIframe();" id="visu" ';
    if ($sem_visualizar == 0)
        echo 'style="background-color: darkgray; color: black;"';
    else if ($sem_visualizar<=5)
        echo 'style="background-color: green;"';
    else if ($sem_visualizar>5 && $sem_visualizar <= 15)
        echo 'style="background-color: orangered;"';
    else if ($sem_visualizar>15)
        echo 'style="background-color: red;"';

        echo '>'.$sem_visualizar.'</label>';
    }
?>
```

Basically it just changes color based on value, but the thing is:
I want it to auto refresh it's own value via the PHP file which returns count, but I have absolutely no idea how can i do this.

I found this code in another answer, but it's not working.

```
<script>
    function get_msg_count(){
        $.ajax ({
            data: {}, // not really needed
            type: 'POST',
            url:  'contar_sem_visualizar.php', // page to return your msg count
            success: function(response)
            {
                $('#visu').html(response);
            }
            }
        }); // End $.ajax
    } // End Function

    // and on DOM ready
    $(function(){
        // check for new messages every 3 seconds(3000ms)
        setInterval(get_msg_count(), 3000)
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What's the output of the PHP?

Comment: the number of rows the mysql query could find

Comment: Is the page that returns your count 'contar_sem_visualizar.php'? You need to replicate your if statement within the success function if response is only a row count.

Comment: yes that's the page, what you mean by replicate?

Comment: if (response <=5) { $("#visu").css("background-color", "green"); } etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [`$.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to achieve that:

**HTML**

```
<span id="count"></span>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#count").load("contar_sem_visualizar.php");
```

Comment: It's refreshing my page nonstop.

Comment: Right, you can also use the callback function to do even more. http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function

Comment: @Phiter Fernandes where are you placing the above code?

Comment: Yeah, @Phiter Fernandes where are you placing the above code? It should be attached to an event.

Comment: You can put it inside `setInterval()`.

Comment: God, I was such a noob back then. The reason it didn't work is because I was passing a function call to setInterval, not a function.

Comment: @Phiter Ha ha... `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You need an element to set the count and use jQuery to put the answer in there. The return from your PHP will be retrieved from the jQuery request and ever after a set interval the client's browser will send a request asking for this value, which will be added again to the counter.

You could do that:

```
function get_count(){
    while()
    {
    $("#counter").load("contar_sem_visualizar.php");
    setInterval(3000);
    }

}
get_count();
```